# A question about an intersection number

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors, blow-ups

Let $\pi:Y\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^3$ be the blow-up of two points $p,q\in\mathbb{P}^3$, and then of the strict transform of the line $L$ spanned by them. Now, Let $E_p,E_q, E_{p,q}$ be respectively the exceptional divisors over $p,q$ and $L$. Therefore $E_p,E_q$ are isomorphic to the blow-up of a point in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $E_{p,q}\cong \mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$. Let $\sigma_{p,q}\subset E_{p,q}$ be the class of the $\mathbb{P}^1$ which is not contracted by $\pi$. Therefore:

$$E_p\cdot \sigma_{p,q} = E_q\cdot\sigma_{p,q} = 1.$$

What is the intersection number $E_{p,q}\cdot \sigma_{p,q}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E$ is the exceptional divisor of a smooth blowup, the restriction of $O(E)$ to $E$ is the relative $O(-1)$ for $E = P_Z(N)$, where $Z$ is the center of the blowup and $N$ is the normal bundle. In your case $Z$ is the proper preimage of the line $L$ in the blowup of two points, consequently $N = O_L(-1) \oplus O_L(-1)$. This means that $O_E(E)$ is the line bundle $O(-1,-1)$. Hence $E\cdot\sigma = -1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to compute $E_{p,q}^3$, $E_{p,q}^2\cdot E_p$, $E_{p}^3$, $E_{p,q}\cdot E_p^2$, $H\cdot E_{p,q}^2$? I added it in the question. From your answer I guess $E_{p,q}^3 = -2$. Is this correct?